# What's is the right reducer architecture for storing domain data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, architecture

I have some domain data, for example, data describing a course.

We need to consider, that:

1. Pagination and filtering are implemented at the server side.
2. There are different types of course (your courses, public courses, closed courses and etc.)
3. There is a different depth of describing of course (some general description, detailed description)

There are about five different pages, that use the same domain data (course).

1. **The main page**: the list of public courses / general description.
2. **The page with the list of all courses**: the list of public courses / detailed description
3. **Your profile page**: list of your courses / general description
4. **Your current courses page**: list of your current courses / detailed description
5. **Your completed courses page**: list of your completed courses / detailed description
6. **Your successes**: list of your completed courses / detailed description / without pagination

I decided to use the per page reducer architecture:

```
{
    main: {
        courses: {
            filters: { ... },
            pagination: { ... },
            data: [
                {
                    <general>
                },
                ...
            ]
        }
    },
    listCourses: {
        courses: {
            filters: { ... },
            pagination: { ... },
            data: [
                {
                    <detailed>
                },
                ...
            ]
        }
    },
    profile: {
        main: {
            courses: {
                filters: { ... },
                pagination: { ... },
                data: [
                    {
                        <general>
                    },
                    ...
                ]
            }
        },
        current: {
            courses: {
                filters: { ... },
                pagination: { ... },
                data: [
                    {
                        <detailed>
                    },
                    ...
                ]
            }
        },
        completed: {
            courses: {
                filters: { ... },
                pagination: { ... },
                data: [
                    {
                        <detailed>
                    },
                    ...
                ]
            },
        }
        success: {
            courses: {
                pagination: { ... },
                data: [
                    {
                        <detailed>
                    },
                    ...
                ]
            }
        },  
    },
}
```

But my colleagues said that per page reducers architecture is ugly and I should not use it, especially because [the creator of Redux doesn't suppose](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/715507393828884480) that it's a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to keep state as flat as possible, and use [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect)

https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuringreducers/normalizingstateshape

Comment: How reselect would be helpful for server-side filtering and searching?